# Is there an app embedding the Flash player?

Tags: macos, applications, adobe-flash

Is there an app embedding the Flash player? I don't want to install the flash player in osx. I just want to use this app when I need it. Does it exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Chrome comes with its own instance of Flash that runs only when it needs it and only within the scope of Chrome. I have uninstalled Flash from all my Macs and simply turn to Chrome when I *really* need Flash for something.

Answer (score 2):

Google chrome both includes and updates it's own Flash plugin.  You can also setup a command key shortcut for opening your current safari page into Chrome for the instances when you actually need Flash.  See [here](http://daringfireball.net/2010/11/flash_free_and_cheating_with_google_chrome) for more info.